# Phantom object after add in ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx

If I want to add an item to the observable list, the item will show up twice. The second item is not in the observable list and can't be selected. 
The forceRedraw function isn't working either in this case.

Code:

```
private Parent createPane(){
    ListView<Customer> allCustomers = new ListView<>();
    allCustomers.setItems(obsCustomerList);
    allCustomers.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Customer>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Customer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(empty) return;
            setText(item.getName());
            if(item.getName().isEmpty()) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
            }
        }
    });
    allCustomers.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(oldValue != null){
            if(!oldValue.getName().equals(name.getText()) || !oldValue.getPhoneNr().equals(phoneNr.getText())){
                oldValue.setName(name.getText());
                oldValue.setPhoneNr(phoneNr.getText());
                changedCustomers.add(oldValue);
                forceRedraw(allCustomers);
            }
        }
        if(newValue != null){
            name.setText(newValue.getName());
            phoneNr.setText(newValue.getPhoneNr());
        }
    });

    Button add = new Button("+");
    add.setPrefSize(30,30);
    add.setOnAction(ae -> {
        Customer newOne = new Customer("New Customer", "");
        obsCustomerList.add(newOne);
        allCustomers.getSelectionModel().select(newOne);
        forceRedraw(allCustomers);
    });
    Button del = new Button("-");
    del.setPrefSize(30,30);

    HBox buttonBox = new HBox(add, del);
    VBox.setVgrow(buttonBox, Priority.NEVER);

    VBox leftSide = new VBox(allCustomers, buttonBox);
    leftSide.setPrefWidth(150);

    name = new TextField();
    name.disableProperty().bind(allCustomers.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
    phoneNr = new TextField();
    phoneNr.disableProperty().bind(allCustomers.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());

    GridPane rightSide = new GridPane();
    rightSide.setVgap(5);
    rightSide.setHgap(5);
    rightSide.add(new Label("Name: "), 0,0);
    rightSide.add(name, 1,0);
    rightSide.add(new Label("Phone Nr: "), 0,1);
    rightSide.add(phoneNr,1,1);

    HBox root = new HBox(leftSide, rightSide);
    root.setPrefSize(400,300);
    root.setSpacing(10);
    return root;
}
private <T> void forceRedraw(ListView<T> lsv){
        ObservableList<T> list = lsv.getItems();
        lsv.setItems(null);
        lsv.setItems(list);
    }
```

The important piece is

```
add.setOnAction(ae -> {
            Customer newOne = new Customer("New Customer", "");
            obsCustomerList.add(newOne);
            allCustomers.getSelectionModel().select(newOne);
            forceRedraw(allCustomers);
        });
```

Gif:[Gyazo Gif Link](https://gyazo.com/201db23c0335359fea8a00a22d345451)

As you can see, i can click all the objects except the last phantom one, which shouldnt even be there.

No worries, the names/phone numbers are not real.

UPDATE: if i delete the CellFactory, the phantom doesn't show up. Is it possible that the CellFactory is called to many times?

Comment: You must clean up the cell in your cell factory if the cell becomes empty. See the question linked.

Comment: Thank you! That was the Problem